# Run time error 9, out of range, error 438, error 1009

Tags: excel, vba

My excel VBA code keeps giving me errors. I was running a lot of code perfectly fine a few days ago. Now I am working on new code, and it is not working!

some errors it gives me include

```
Run time error 9, out of range
error 438
error 1009
```

I think something is wrong, that does not necessarily have to do with the code

```
Sub GetTickers1()

    WS = Workbooks("Ticker Symbols for Rodman and Renshaw Conference 2015").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To i = 254 Step 1



    WS.Cells(i, 2) = Left(Right("" + WS.Cells(i, 1), 5), 4)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Also this: `For i = 2 To i = 254 Step 1` should be: `For i = 2 To 254 Step 1` (though the Step 1 is optional)

Comment: If you place the words "Option Explicit" at the very top of your form or module you will be able to stay away from some of these issues. It will tell you when things are not right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code was never working (at least not as it is currently written).

The very first line cannot execute without the `Set` keyword and will raise the 438 error.

If you rectify that error, then you can expect a 1009 error if either:

- The workbook specified on the right-side of that statement isn't open in the current active instance of Excel Application
- The worksheet specified on the right-side of that statement doesn't exist within the workbook specified.

For your 424 error, while you can sometimes rely on an object's *default property* while (e.g., `Debug.Print Range("A1")` will print the `.Value`), an assignment statement doesn't automatically assign to the default property, so you'll have to specify: `WS.Cells(i, 2).Value = ...` Also, I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `"" +` but that could causing a type mismatch -- read up on whether it's preferable to use the `+` or `&` operator for concatenating strings -- both are allowable, but the `+` can get you in trouble sometimes, so revised as:

```
WS.Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(Right(WS.Cells(i, 1), 5), 4)
```

NB also that your `For i = 2 To i = 254 Step 1` will not do anything. Try instead `For i = 2 to 254`.  A step of 1 is always implied unless otherwise specified, so you don't need to explicitly do `Step 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **Set** in the first line.

Comment: I updated the code to this

Sub GetTickers1()

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 254 Step 1



Set WS.Cells(i, 2) = Left(Right("" + WS.Cells(i, 1), 5), 4)

Next i

End Sub

but now it just gives me run time error 424 on the 5th line

Comment: This is my code nowSub GetTickers1()

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 254 Step 1



Set WS.Cells(i, 2) = Left(Right("" + WS.Cells(i, 1), 5), 4)

Next i

End Sub